# How to get camera2 preview frames programmatically(without layout) in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera2, surface, textureview

I've create a foreground service with the intention of getting frames from camera2 preview without displaying a layout to user. When I create a Textureview in the layout and use it, everything works fine and I can get the frames via calling getBitmap(int width, int height) of TextureView. I've saved the frames and I know it works fine. Here is my code:

```
textureView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
```

But I need my code to work without a layout. I've created a TextureView programmatically but when I run it and save the frames, they're blank. This is the code I run to make it work without layout:

```
textureView = new TextureView(context);
textureView.setSurfaceTexture(new SurfaceTexture(100));
surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
```

FYI, I run my code on a worker thread. I've also tried using Listeners of these objects but no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid using a surface.
But maybe you can get away with dynamically inflating it with layout height and width 0dp.